# AngularJS ignoring whitespace in string

Tags: regex, angularjs, whitespace

I am having hard time finding out how can I get AngularJS not to ignore whitespaces in strings. Im trying to validate password requirements with AngularJS directive and regex pattern and problem is that I dont want to allow leading or trailing whitespace in password.

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GX5Kr/9/

```
var regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,})$/;
```

Comment: `[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]foo[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]` reports length `3` instead of `13` - are you sure it doesn't `trim` the output?

Comment: No trimming in fiddle

Comment: There is nothing in the regex that allows for leading/trailing spaces since the final constraint is `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}` and its all wrapped with ^$ anchors. Must be something else.

Comment: I DONT want to allow whitespaces.

Comment: That regex will NEVER match a whitespace.

Comment: Yes. That is not my problem. Problem is angularjs striping all whitespaces off from variables. That way i cant never check them. See fiddle before commenting...

Comment: I tried to go to the fiddle, but my browser is too old, not supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get trailing white space from input type password to scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621472/get-trailing-white-space-from-input-type-password-to-scope)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [Get trailing white space from input type password to scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621472/get-trailing-white-space-from-input-type-password-to-scope)

You're probably looking for `ng-trim="false"`. This will update your model including spaces typed into your `<input>`.

I updated your fiddle for proof. 
http://jsfiddle.net/GX5Kr/10/