# angular require directive breaks my own one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive, made after [filters on ng-model in an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/angularjs-filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input/14425022#14425022), that restricts input just to digits:

```
     .directive('onlydigitinput', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')
                  .replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

works great alone, but used together with, apparently, standard directive **required,** it starts to fail.

I use the following HTML (jade syntax):

```
input(type='text' , required, onlydigitinput,  min='1', max='99', maxlength='2')
```

(I do not use type='number' as it messes with maxlength: [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome), and also disregards my directive as well)

When I enter digits, it works fine. Field is valid.
When I try to enter digit and then some letter, it works fine: field is valid, and I can not enter non-digit.
But when I start from non-digit, field is invalid but I can still enter letters, that is accompanied by the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/core/directives/systemDirectives.js:63:54
```

referring to the use of toLowerCase in directive above. Please advice how I can clear this error and make my directive perform well also in the latter case, and avoid the error.

Comment: It seems to **[work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/bVv3z/)**. What is the problem ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem if you add required directive to input, it starts to allow letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a required field validator on the input field. Hence, when you set the field to blank("") - happens when you type non-digit. The value becomes **undefined**.

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')
              .replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
            if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }
```

Add the below on top of above code:

```
if(!inputValue) return ;
```