# Apply number filter on input field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do we apply number filter on input field? I works fine on displaying on non-input field. However when I set the filter on input field I get an error.

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="value2 | number:2"
             min="0" max="99" size="20">
```

> Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/ngModel/numfmt?p0=98.77
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:6:416

Here is a plunk for testing.
[number format](http://plnkr.co/edit/XFfbtqIvD8x4Ekq3mtRh?p=preview)

Comment: You cannot apply filter on `ng-model` ng-model needs to be a property on the scope that can be assigned to

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a `filter` to `ng-model`.

See specifically this answer (not marked as **the** answer) for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425022/1452497

Short and sweet:

> ...the intention of AngularJS inputs and the ngModel
>   directive is that invalid input should never end up in the model. The
>   model should be always valid.

Consider also that the *expression* inside of `ng-model` needs to be *assignable* from the parser.

`ng-model="testA"` eventually breaks down to: `testA = some-input-value`

This wouldn't work as: `testA | number:2 = some-input-value`

You should use a `formatter` or `parser` for this (outside of the view).

Answer (score 1):

```
This error: 
Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/ngModel/numfmt?p0=1
check your model: don't using $scope.mymodel = '1';
to use $scope.mymodel = 1;
```

This directive validate only numbers on input.

```
angularMainModule.directive('onlyNumbers', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var keyCode = [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,
                     96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,110];
        element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
            if($.inArray(event.which,keyCode) == -1) {
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                     scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNumbers);
                     event.preventDefault();`enter code here`
                 });
                 event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```