# In AngularJS, howto use ng-trim=false with input type as email

Tags: angularjs, email

I am having login form with two fields ..username and password. Now by default angular trim white spaces from email field.
But I want to retain white spaces so that I can show invalid email field message based on white space.
How  can I retain white spaces in input type email field?
( I know we can use ng-trim="false" to avoid trim but it is application in case of input type =text only )
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Here your directive will look like

**Directive**

```
app.directive('customValidation', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="sth" ng-trim="false" custom-validation>
```

Here is [**Reference SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input)