# Using filter inside ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the following filter inside a h3:

```
{{ event.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

And is working just fine, the angular is formatting and showing the date like I want. I'm trying to apply the same filter inside an `ng-model`:

```
ng-model="event.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"
```

And this is not working, is throwing an error:

```
Error: ngModel:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression
Expression 'event.date' is non-assignable. Element: {1}
```

Could you someone explain me why?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible the way you are trying to do.

An alternate solution will be using `input masking`. There are some libraries available already for the task such as ngMask and angular-input-masks.

https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask

https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

ng-model needs a variable that it can 2-way data-bind to but the filters output is not assignable.