# Angular filter "Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression '(gridData.StructureViewModel | sumPlanByKpi:kpi)' is non-assignable."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Pls, help me resolve this error. And what i do wrong?

I have this INPUT with custom filter **| sumPlanByKpi:kpi**

```js
filterModule.filter('sumPlanByKpi', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, kpi) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(input) && angular.isUndefined(kpi))
            return 0;
        var sum = 0;

        var findedPlansArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var findedPlans = $filter('filter')(input[i].Plans, function (plan) { return plan.KPI_ID === kpi.ID; });
            var temp = findedPlansArray.concat(findedPlans);
            findedPlansArray = temp;
        }
        angular.forEach(findedPlansArray, function (v, k) {
            if (v.Value != null)
                sum = sum + parseInt(v.Value);
        });
        return sum;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-lg-1" ng-model="(gridData.StructureViewModel | sumPlanByKpi:kpi)"
             disabled="" pattern="^[0-9]*$" min="0" max="1e+22" step="1"
             awnum num-sep=',' num-neg=false num-int=40 num-fract=0 num-thousand=true num-thousand-sep="{{' '}}">
```

[IMAGE - And I get this errors on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oC6K.png)

Comment: You cannot use filter with `ng-model`. This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input

Comment: But this work right. Only throw errors. Why? If this wrong action, then why this work?

Comment: I find answer for my question. I should use ng-value for input for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find answer for my question. I should use **ng-value** for input in this case instead of **ng-model**.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-lg-1" ng-value="(gridData.StructureViewModel | sumPlanByKpi:kpi)"
         disabled="" pattern="^[0-9]*$" min="0" max="1e+22" step="1"
         awnum num-sep=',' num-neg=false num-int=40 num-fract=0 num-thousand=true num-thousand-sep="{{' '}}">
```