# Create an AngularJS filter to remove regular expression matches and replace with masked text in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

My goal is to create an angular filter that could be placed on a textarea or input such that when a user types text that matches a predefined regular expression, the text would be identified and replaced with a masked form of that text.

Is this possible using a filter? Or should I be approaching it differently? I'd provide what I've started, but it's so far off that I'm not sure it would help at all. Even a solid starting point and confirmation that I'm approaching this correctly (or not), would be helpful.

Comment: Add some codes, what have you tried right now?

Comment: nothing wrong with writing it as a filter. Can use that filter inside a directive to update ngModel if needed by using `$filter` service. So it will be versatile regardless of how you finally implement it. Or write it in a service. Whatever you do it will be easy to move around if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a directive is the easiest way to do this because filters can't be included on ng-model bindings.

Based on that, and ***heavy help*** (this could probably be marked as a duplicate question) from the 2nd answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input), I got it working the way I wanted.

```
angular.module("app").directive('customValidation', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl: ng.INgModelController) {

                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

                    var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/microsoft/i, "W3Schools");


                    if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                    }

                    return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        };
    });

<textarea ng-model="vm.text" ng-trim="false" custom-validation></textarea>
```