# Angular JS Json Datetime filter use from input

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, json, datetime

this is my filter function(from json date convert):

```
app.filter("mydate", function () {
var re = /\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//;
return function (x) {
    var m = x.match(re);
    if (m) return new Date(parseInt(m[1]));
    else return null;
};
```

});

no problem if I use it here:

```
{{k.StartDate | mydate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}
```

I want to use this filter in input , but I'm getting this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sok1m.png)

I use the filter like this

```
<input class="w-100" datetime="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate | mydate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'" type="text">
```

Comment: Yes. You can't filter model.

Comment: [you can't filter an ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input). I think the solution you want is a custom directive and not a filter. Apply changes within a directive, possibly with `ngModel.$parsers.push(function (input) { ...`

Comment: try to use <input class="w-100" datetime="yyyy-MM-dd" value="{{ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate | mydate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}" type="text">

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a filter on ng-model. I suggest you watching the changes with ng-change and applying the filter on the controller, like this:

```
<input class="w-100" datetime="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate" ng-change="applyFilter()" type="text">
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.applyFilter = function(){
    $scope.ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate = $filter('mydate')($scope.ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate);
    $scope.ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate = $filter('date')($scope.ApplyToProgress.CurrentWork.StartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    }
```