# angularjs: taking only numbers (which are upto 10 char length)

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am developing first time in angular and my requirement is the input should take only digits up to length 10.
After lot of searches I know that I can either use input type as number which will restrict only numbers but the issue with this is it allows e character as exponential sigh and - sign for the math numbers. I do not want this. What I need is the text area should only allow numbers up to length 10 chars.
Hence I am using input type as text like below:

in my component template I defined something like below:

```
$
 <div class="number">
   <input type="text" formControlName="Q4a" maxlength="10" ng-
   pattern="onlyNumbers" required /><!"/^[0-9]{1,7}$"  ---->
                </div>   


onlyNumbers = '/^\d+$/';
$
```

but this does not work. The max length allowed is 10 chars but it does allow characters.
How do I achieve what I need, which is an input area that allows only digits up to 10 characters?

Comment: try changing it to `pattern="^\d{1,10}$"`

Comment: Add `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"` attribute to the `input` element.

Comment: Matt G,that didn't work.

Comment: Also, check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425022/3832970).

Comment: If nothing works, please share a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) or [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Wiktor,  that worked! thank you!