# AngularJS: Should I use a filter to convert integer values into percentages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need to collect a rate of change - in percentages - from my application's users. Here is the text input I am using:

```
<label for="annual-change" class="pt-underline"> I am anticipating
<input id="annual-change" ng-model="calc.yrChange"  type="text" placeholder="0" /> % of growth annually.<br><br>
</label>
```

Now what I want is to use a filter that takes the integer amount that the user inputs and convert it to a percentage by multiplying it by `0.01` or dividing it by `100` *before I send it to the controller for calculations*

But I just can't figure out where to place the filter and how to hook it. So I tried it with a directive like so:

```
    app.directive("percent", function($filter){
    var p = function(viewValue){
      console.log(viewValue);
      var m = viewValue.match(/^(\d+)/);
      if (m !== null)
        return $filter('number')(parseFloat(viewValue)/100);
    };

    var f = function(modelValue){
        return $filter('number')(parseFloat(modelValue)*100);
    };

    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl){
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(p);
          ctrl.$formatters.unshift(f);
      }
    };
});
```

This kind of works but shouldn't I be using a filter for this task? How do I do this?

Comment: Filter are there to map content of one array to another. I think you should do the conversion in controller. What is stopping you from using controller.

Comment: hmm - I thought filters were for `filtering` values so I thought formatting, conversion etc should be in filters

Comment: There are a no of fields that need to go through this conversion and I thought the logic would get repeated in the controller

Comment: One more thing filter do not update the model data, they just transform. Directive is a right way to go. Let me think about it

Comment: My bad filter can map one type another, but my last comment holds

Comment: I love directives, but in this case I think a filter is the better choices. It makes (imo) for a more readable template to have a thing | asPercent instead of a directive.

Comment: Oh wait, my bad. Using a filter to modify data before sending it to the controller is kind of strange, I was thinking using a filter to simply represent data in the template as percentages. Then I agree, filter is probably strange (and I am not sure it even works on an input like that).

Comment: Thanks; I've used this cut-down version based on kfis' feedback below.
```
    app.directive 'percent', ->
      require: 'ngModel'
      link: (scope, ele, attr, ctrl) ->
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift (val) -> (parseFloat(val) / 100)
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift (val) -> Math.round(val * 100) + "%"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you just did it the absolute right way with the ctrl.$parser and ctrl.$formatter
You just can leave out the $filter thing, its absulotuly not needed there.
[Just check it out](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) they don't use the filter there, too.

Comment: You are right - it works - here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pfzyn4Bmw2B9jJzDVU1g?p=preview

Comment: Actually I am really surprised that you came so far of doing all these correct things with the directive, the required ngModelDirective, formatters and all and suddenly have this filter-blooper :)

Comment: ok so I actually found that code snippet on SO and it seemed and still seems quite cryptic to me. I would have thought a filter transforms model data and passes it along from the view to the controller but that a'int so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a directive. If you think you are about to fall back to using JQuery to start manipulating the DOM elements then a directive is probably what you want.

This is an example of a filter: http://embed.plnkr.co/TT6ZwOF6nYXwMcemR3JF/preview

What you could do is filter the value you enter as part of a watch event. However that depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Appreciate the example but I think what I did not understand is that filters only represent data - they don't update the model data - so I guess I want is something that does that - in that case my code example still stands