# Inject percentage filter in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

When invoking ng-strict-di on my ng-app I receive an error "Error: [$injector:strictdi] percentageFilter is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode" on line

```
<span ng-hide="item.edit" ng-bind="item.tax | percentage"></span>
```

I have tried using the string "percentage" and percentageFilter" in my injection to solve the issue.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("transaction", ['$scope', 'CustomerService', '$state', '$filter', '$modal', 'ngTableParams', 'JobService', 'OrderService', 'toastr', '$timeout','percentageFilter', function ($scope, CustomerService, $state, $filter, $modal, ngTableParams, JobService, OrderService, toastr, $timeout,percentageFilter) {}});
```

What is the proper way to inject the percentage filter or any other filters in strictdi mode?

Filter in question:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('percentage', function ($window) {
 return function (input, decimalForm) {
    if ($window.isNaN(input))
        return '';
    else if (input == 0)
        return '-';
    else return decimalForm ? (input/100).toFixed(2) : (input*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
 };
});
```

Comment: I dont think there is a built in `percentage` filter. Have you created one?

Comment: Here is an answer you can look at to create the filter in first place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668440/how-to-make-a-percent-formatted-input-work-on-latest-angularjs

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code. Custom filters work fine with ng-strict-di: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDFLZecdjhFawbLQu1Ji?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev What is wrong in the code is that there is no built in percentage filter.

Comment: @PSL, I am assuming that the OP meant to use a custom filter.

Comment: @NewDev title and the question doesn't say so though... Probably last sentence made it more generic. You may be right. However this case i guess OP has no such filter.

Comment: Try with some other filter for instance, `numberFilter` and see if it gets injected fine

Comment: Filter exists as it works just fine without the strict-di

Comment: Then ur filter code is not using proper dependency annotation. You need to show the filter instead of where you are using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the way you are injecting the filter instead the issue is with the filter itself. You are not using explicit dependency annotation for the `percentageFilter`.
i.e `angular.module('mYapp').filter('percentage', ['$window', function ($window) {`:

Try:

```
angular.module('mYapp').filter('percentage', ['$window', function ($window) {
 return function (input, decimalForm) {
    if ($window.isNaN(input))
        return '';

    if (input == 0)
        return '-';

    return decimalForm ? (input/100).toFixed(2) : (input*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
 };
}]);
```