# Updating only the 'view' value using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-model

So I have a decimal value in controller like this:

```
// Controller
var MyController = function($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.percentValue = 0.05; // can be stored
    ...
};

<!-- View -->
<span>{{percentValue}}</span>
<input ng-model="percentValue" />
```

With the above code, the value in the `input` element is `0.05` - however, I want to allow a user to enter an integer value like `5`.

So if the *$scope.percentValue* is `0.05`, I want to show it as `5` in the input element.  And if a user enters `5`, the *$scope.percentValue* should be `0.05`.

However, the tricky thing here is **I only want to update the view value** - meaning that the `span` element should still show `0.05`.  Only the value in the input element should be `5`.

I am trying to achieve this with *ngModel*, but I am still struggling.

This is what I have now:

```
var MyDirective = function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.val(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
            return value * 100;
        });

        element.on('change blur', function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
        }); 
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: link
    };
};
```

Please advise!!

Comment: try a filter instead.

Comment: @KimchiMan, you're already using `$formatters` to transform the model representation for display, so just simply define a `$parsers` to do it the other way, like so—http://plnkr.co/edit/lB6GaT1ZSrVsOi9PS1u9?p=preview

Comment: @miqid, your answer is exactly what I want - could you add the code in the answer section? I will mark it as the answer

Comment: @miqid also, I wonder if there is a way to achieve this without using `value / 100`

Comment: @KimchiMan, are there any restrictions on what a user is expected, or allowed, to enter in that input? Any other context for what you're building might also help. If `$formatters` is already doing `value * 100`, I don't see why `value / 100` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @miqid Yeah - when I saw the cycle of $formatters and $parser, it does make sense - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including my comment as an answer because it seemed to help. :-)

To summarise: since you've already provided a `$formatters` function for your directive, which converts a model value (`$modelValue`) to displayed form (`$viewValue`), it's simply a matter of providing a `$parsers` function to do the reverse and convert any user input back to the model value.

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lB6GaT1ZSrVsOi9PS1u9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is *probably* possible, but I would find it really confusing to read the code. The simplest solution that I think would solve your problem and maintain readability is to store an integer value (`5`) in `$scope.percentValue`, so that `ng-model` is always dealing with an integer when typing and displaying the value in the `<input>`. Then create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) and use it to output the value as `0.05` in the `<span>`.

Edit: adding a concrete code example. Play with it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/C1cX2L9B2GM2yax1rw7Z?p=preview

JS:

```
var MyController = function ($scope) {
  $scope.percentValue = 5;
};

function formatPercent (input) {
  return input / 100;
}

var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
myApp.filter('percent', function () { return formatPercent });
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <span>{{ percentValue | percent }}</span>
  <input ng-model="percentValue">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a filter for percentage :

```
angular.module('myModule')
.filter('percentage', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, decimals) {
        return $filter('number')(input*100, decimals)+'%';
    };
}]);
```

The input will store integer (such as 5)

```
<input ng-model="percentValue" />
```

But I'll add a filter to the span part :

```
<span>{{percentValue | percentage:2}}</span>
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21727765/3687474 for the filter directive.

Answer (score 0):

Other than creating a filter you can also calculate on the template

`<span>{{percentValue * 100}}</span>`